# How do i write a bash script to loop through each directory in a folder and append all .txt files into a single file?

Tags: bash, macos, concatenation, text-files

IN BASH: 
I have a directory containing a bunch of folders that each contain a .txt file I'd like to loop through each folder in the directory and concatenated all of the text files into one file. When I try the code I wrote below, I see bash is looping through each folder but nothing is added to the mergedfile:

```
for f in *; do
    if [ -d ${f} ]; then
        cd ${f}
        cat -name "*.txt" > mergedfile
        echo $f
        cd ..
    fi
done
```

I also noticed this error after each loop:

```
cat: illegal option -- a
usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]
```

Comment: `find . -name "*.txt" -exec cat "{}" ";" > my-file`. Use `-maxdepth X` to suite.

Comment: `cat */*/*.txt` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appends the output to all.txt

```
cat *.txt >> all.txt
```

This overwrites all.txt

```
cat *.txt > all.txt
```

Correction in your code:

```
v="$PWD/mergedfile"    
for f in *; do
        if [ -d ${f} ]; then
            cd ${f}
            cat *.txt >> ${v}
            echo $f
            cd ..
        fi
    done
```

Comment: Correct, but `cat */*.txt >mergedfile` seem simplier!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I just corrected his solution.

Comment: @user1858409 Did you try my purpose?? It's a lot simplier!

Answer (score 0):

## Basically

For only 1 level of directory, this will do the job:

```
cat */*.txt >mergedfile
```

## using globstar

For any level (0 or more) of subdirectories, you could use *`globstar`* bash option:

```
shopt -s globstar
cat **/*.txt >mergedfile
```